# How to block file overwrite on Network share drive using file system minifilter

Tags: c++, minifilter

I have created a minifilter driver to block the access of files in network share drive. It is working fine .
Here I face an issue, not able to block file editing in it.
I have checked with the following flag values in miniprecreate method.
FILE_OVERWRITE , FILE_WRITE_DATA, FILE_APPEND_DATA, FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES, FILE_WRITE_EA
Here is the sample code which I have used.

```
if((Data->Iopb->Parameters.Create.Options >> 24) ==FILE_APPEND_DATA )                           
                    {

                        Data->IoStatus.Status=STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;
                        Data->IoStatus.Information=0;
                        FltReleaseFileNameInformation(FileNameInfos);
                        return FLT_PREOP_COMPLETE;
                    }
```

But not able to block file edition.
Thanks in advance. Can you please provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

regist  IRP_MJ_WRITE and block that use the same way without 
if((Data->Iopb->Parameters.Create.Options >> 24) ==FILE_APPEND_DATA )